# Custom email layout handle for custom module

Tags: php, email, magento

I have created a custom module, In which i am sending email to customer.
email is working fine but i have created a layout handle in layout/test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <my_name_is_hello>
        <block type="core/template" name="hello"  template="test/sales/items.phtml"></block>
    </my_name_is_hello>
</layout>
```

this is my content in test/sales/items.phtml

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Now i have called layout handle in my email template file hello.phtml using both method but file is not getting called.

```
{{layout handle="my_name_is_hello"}}
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='test/sales/items.phtml'}}
```

Please can anybody suggest me if i am doing something wrong or any solution

Answer (score 0):

//Add template file in email content.

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/custom.phtml' order=$order}}
```

//Add phtml file in following path.

```
app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/email/custom.phtml
```